# Ai Assistant programming guidance needed

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Can any one tell me or guide me in programming an ai Assistant something like Jarvis or Google Assistant etc which has both online and offline voice recognition capability.
I am new to Ai so I tried many tuorials and all still not able to understand or build one. Also don't know where to start and how to start please any help I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be frank, natural language processing is one of the most complex and technically difficult fields in computer science. so if you want to make your own version of google assistant, it would help to have an advanced degree in AI, a million dollars in research funding and your own team of engineers.

That being said, a chatbot makes for a really fun hobby project. For now, try not to worry about online and offline voice recognition capability. Make a text-based chatbot that handles basic conversation. You can always add more capability later, and you'll probably have your bearings by then and know what to do.

A good place may be [microsoft's new bot framework](https://dev.botframework.com/). I've never used it, myself, but its goal is to take some of the technologies behind the likes of Google Assistant and Jarvis, and to make them available for the everyday developer. It seems to fit your use-case, and as a microsoft product, it'll (probably) have some documentation or tutorials for you to get started.

Comment: I disagree. I made that from a 100£ broken laptop after 1 year of programming. You just need determination, or better said, an obsession to do that.  You need to think like a $e*ually obsessed person, just in the computer field.     Look here: https://github.com/CSharpTeoMan911/Eva

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to get started.
First off, try to build a

> `bot using C# for native windows`

applications. Microsoft has great documentation for the same, and there are a couple of great tutorials on YouTube for the same.
You can also try

> `api.ai`

to build a bot. It's a bit less hands on, but a good way to get started. 
To really try doing everything yourself, try learning a bot of machine learning first. Google has great YouTube tutorials for the same.

Try:
[C# bot on windows](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=n2FadWBTL9E)
[Google machine learning](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT6elRN3Aer7ncFlaCz8Zz-4B5cnsrOMt)

Comment: Thanks for helping. Would you be kind enough to share the links for the tutorial .

Answer (score 0):

The best choice to start is api.ai. It is simple to learn and integrate, and have a good response time. I tried most of the chatbot engines, apply to the natural language by phone to build voice assistants (Voximal). An important factor in this case is the response time. If you plan to integrate a lot of complex datas the reponse time will increase, and remember that you need to add the time duration of the SpeechToText and TextToSpeech too...

Answer (score 0):

Use my project as an inspiration, is a personal A.I. assistant that is running on Windows 10/11(maybe even 8, not tested). It uses Tokenization and content analysis and association with set parameters for natural language processing and offline and online speech recognition for speech recognition. It can search content on Amazon, Google, Google Images, Google News, Netflix, Wikipedia and eBay. It can open and close multiple applications and it can also navigate in the settings menu on windows on any page or sub-section.

The project is here:  https://github.com/CSharpTeoMan911/Eva